# Draw polygons with highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I need to draw polygons with highcharts. The thing is that I need exactly one tooltip and a mouseover effect for the whole polygon. To get an idea of what I want to achieve, look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lfchm0e/1).

```js
    Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            type: 'column',
            zoomType: 'x'
        },
        xAxis: [{
            categories: [
                'Jan 17',
                'Feb 17',
                'Mar 17',
                'Apr 17',
                'May 17',
                'Jun 17',
                'Jul 17',
                'Aug 17',
                'Sep 17',
                'Oct 17',
                'Nov 17',
                'Dec 17'
            ]
        }],
        series: [
        {
            type: 'area',
            data: [150,140,140, 140, 150, 150,100, 100,150, 150,150, 150],
            color: '#ababab',
            step: 'left',
            marker: {
              enabled: false
            }
        }]
    });
```

You notice that there is a tooltip for each point. What I want is one tooltip which is displayed at the top-middle position of that figure. And I also need that mouseover effect which you might know from column charts. I guess this is not possible with highcharts default api, is it? Anyone tried to do such things?

Comment: Do you want the mouseover effect to happen on a single segment (e.g. between Jul '17 and Sep '17 in the example that you provided) or on the whole series?

Comment: No, I want the tooltip to be displayed on the whole series.

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts provides the **polygon type of series** in which tooltip doesn't follow the boundaries. Using it together with the `tooltip.positioner` will help you achieve the desired effect:

```
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {

  chart: {
    type: 'polygon'
  },

  series: [{
    data: [
      [1, 3],
      [2, 6],
      [4, 1]
    ]
  }],

  tooltip: {
    positioner: function() {
      return {
        x: 300,
        y: 100
      }
    }
  }
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/go9umtfn/

---

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.positioner